# Sending emails using Python smtplib and EmailMessage()

Tags: python, typeerror, smtplib

I'm trying to send message on email using Python smtplib and EmailMessage().

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to  
    user = 'username@gmail.com'
    msg['from'] = user
    password = 'app_password'
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send(msg)
    server.quit()

email_alert("hey", "Hello world","another@mail.com")
```

But error occures "**TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'EmailMessage'**".
What's the problem with the code? I saw video where this code worked.

Comment: maybe you can try `server.send(msg.as_string())`?

Comment: I tied it. Now there's no error, but the message doen't appear at the email adress where it was sent to.

Comment: I found another way to send email but it's still interesting to know why previous example doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to  
    user = 'username@gmail.com'
    msg['from'] = user
    password = 'app_password'
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg) # <- UPDATED
    server.quit()

email_alert("hey", "Hello world","another@mail.com")
```